# Inherit one specific property with LESS

Tags: css, html, inheritance, less

Is possible in LESS make an element inherit only one or more specific properties?

For example (in a stylesheet.less provided from another source so i cannot modify it):

```
.divheader{
   height:50px;
   color: red;
   line-height: 1.5;
}
```

In my stylesheet.less:

```
.mydivheader{
   .divheader;
   color: black;
}
```

In this case it would inherit all the properties not overwritten by my class, but i would like to do something like this:

```
.mydivheader{
   .divheader.height; //invented syntax
   color: black;
}
```

so i only inherit the height property of the divheader class...

How can a do something like this?

Comment: Any reason for not hard-coding the height that you want provided you are not having access to the remote un-editable file?

Comment: No, you cannot do that. Your best option would be to group such properties alone into some mixin/class and then call them wherever needed.

Comment: Not exactly a dupe but your question is somewhat similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28315498/possible-to-reference-extended-property-in-less/28315646#28315646

Comment: @Harry thanks for the question reference, i searched by LESS inheritance instead of extension so i didnt found that question

Comment: @NKL taking into account that the referenced stylesheet could vary in the future i wanted to make this futureproof

Comment: In my specific case i found that the parent element i was extending/inheriting from used variables for the properties i wanted to extend so i used these variables in my element. 
But i would like to know if in general you could do it (extending specific properties directly) now or in a future version of LESS (that would be very useful)

Comment: @ase69s: This is definitely not possible in current version. Not sure if there is any feature request for the future versions. Maybe you could find something in the official GitHub page.

Comment: possible see https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2433

Comment: Harry @BassJobsen thanks, those two possible answers would solve the question (not possible in current version + related github issue, or use variables) if any of you want the merit post it as an answer and i will mark it accordingly